# My website got hijacked, how do I ask search engines to remove the bad webpages

Tags: seo, google-search-console, hacked-site

Today I discovered that 2 days ago my websites got hijacked. A tonne (maybe hundreds/thousands) of new pages were created on my domain that redirected to some Chinese websites. I have since then removed the script that hijacked my website but google has cached my websites. These 2 websites had nothing on them. I just hosted it because I thought "why not". I rather host it than leave it parked with namecheap. So how do I get google and other search engines to remove all these backlinks that were created?

The hijacked domains had nothing important on it. I just dont want my website to be blacklisted on search engines as a bad website

Comment: Go into Search Console!

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE There is no option to recrawl and re-cache my entire website. If there was, there would be only one page, which is index.php

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to get a list of URLs and submit them to google to remove.   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en

Comment: @davidgo when I search for `site:example.com` on google, there are pages upon pages of results of the hacked backlinks

Comment: @davidgo Would I put `https://example.com/` in the clear cache section and that should essentially clear all the cache for all of my website. As said before, both my hacked domains had nothing on it.

Comment: Personally, I would destroy the server and rebuild on a $5 DO droplet. I'd then harden it and put up some legit content that's topically in line with what I'd eventually want to rank for. Submit to search console, wait till it's indexed, and then either leave it alone or shut off the droplet till I actually wanted to build it out.

Comment: @MikeCiffone For right now I just want to delete everything and remove 2 websites off google

Comment: @PaulShan Just turn the server off

Comment: @MikeCiffone I cannot because I have a website hosted on there that I actually need to host. Right now I believe I have removed all the malware, but need to get the bad redirects off search engines

Comment: @PaulShan If you have a production site on the same server as the hacked site you don't care about, to me, that's even more reason to spin up a new server for your production site. I'd keep anything I want to rank as far away as possible.

Comment: Here's a good canonical question from Infosec SE offering some advice for when your server is hacked, though it may be overkill for this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Related: [Shall I submit sitemap containing all the bad (now 404) urls after the spam url hack?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136667/shall-i-submit-sitemap-containing-all-the-bad-now-404-urls-after-the-spam-url)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that can save your domain:

1. Remove all files from the current hosting account
2. Restore the old backup including database
3. Generate a new XML sitemap and submit to the Search Console
4. Once everything is done then fetch your website using Search Console

Comment: can do those steps if you have an old backup  that is cleaned from malware/hijack causer.